# How to retrieve deleted spam mails

Tags: spam-prevention, yahoo-mail

I received an important mail in the spam folder and just as I hit the delete button, I realized its importance, Can I restore this mail ?

Notice that I use Yahoo mail.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it won't be possible. It is deleted forever.

Comment: This answer is not true/blatantly incorrect. Also, when posting answers please try to include some information as to why or how you arrived at the answer.

Answer (score -1):

yes , some times it is possible, you have to use yahoo mail recover.

Comment: Care to give some more details? This isn't very helpful as it is.

Comment: Good and true answer but requires much more detail.